# Unable to update HTML5 canvas pixel color using putImageData in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Here is my complete code:

```
<canvas width="1366" height="768"></canvas>
<script> 
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var data = imageData.data;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
      data[i]     = 0;
      data[i + 1] = 0;
      data[i + 2] = 0;
    }
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
</script>
```

Even though I have set the value of each individual color channel to 0, the canvas remains white as if nothing changed.

This is the only code on the webpage and there is no error in the developer console.

Comment: Just an idea but could it be possible to alpha channel is also 0? Effectively this would make your canvas transparent.

Comment: @Mathyn Is alpha channel always 0 by default for a blank canvas?

Comment: not sure what the default value is. It is most likely defined somewhere in the HTML spec.

Comment: From experience: initially every pixel is fully transparent on Chrome, Firefox, IE11 and Edge.

Comment: The default color is "transparent black", Which is another way of saying the  memory used for the pixel data buffer is zero filled after being  allocated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments your alpha channel is most likely 0 making the canvas transparent. To fix this try the following in your for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
   data[i]     = 0;
   data[i + 1] = 0;
   data[i + 2] = 0;
   data[i + 3] = 255;
}
```