# What besides alpha am I doing wrong in trying to write to a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, opacity

I am trying to draw on a canvas from an array of arrays that should initially be grey `#808080`. None of the permutations I am trying is changing that I have a full-screen canvas that is completely white.

I believe that I have missed some basic step in going from an imageData to a grey rectangle drawn on the screen.

What am I missing, or have I otherwise done wrong?

[What am I missing in putting an image on this canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72770452/what-am-i-missing-in-putting-an-image-on-this-canvas) was closed as a duplicate of [Unable to update HTML5 canvas pixel color using putImageData in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701190/unable-to-update-html5-canvas-pixel-color-using-putimagedata-in-javascript), but adding an alpha of 255 still leaves a white, as opposed to `#808080`, canvas.

```js
(function() {
  var context = null;
  var grid = [];
  var height = null;
  var image_data = null;
  var width = null;

  var draw = function() {
    var data = image_data.data;
    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index += 4) {
      var x = Math.floor(Math.floor(index / 4) / width);
      var y = Math.floor(Math.floor(index / 4) * width);
      data[index] = grid[x][y][0];
      data[index + 1] = grid[x][y][1];
      data[index + 2] = grid[x][y][2];
      data[index + 3] = 255;
    }
    image_data.data = data;
    context.putImageData(image_data, 0, 0);
  };

  var init = function() {
    height = jQuery(window).height();
    width = jQuery(window).width();
    jQuery('#container').html('<canvas id="map" height="' + height + '" width="' + width + '"></canvas>')
    context = document.getElementById('map').getContext('2d');
    image_data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    for (var outer = 0; outer < width; outer += 1) {
      grid[outer] = [];
      for (var inner = 0; inner < height; inner += 1) {
        grid[outer][inner] = [128, 128, 128];
      }
    }
  }

  var start_drawing = function() {
    draw();
    setTimeout(start_drawing, 1);
  };

  init();
  start_drawing();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Your calculation for X&Y looks wrong, did you mean -> `var x = Math.floor(Math.floor(index / 4) % width);
      var y = Math.floor(Math.floor(index / 4) / width);`

Comment: Also, just an aside, but you should try replacing your timeout with `window.requestAnimationFrame`, it will stop your script from trying to render up to 1000 times a second.

Answer (score 0):

The calculations for actually calculating the indexes into your array are wrong.

Let's look at an example - say the width of the canvas is `10` and the height `5`. It's imageData thus contains `200` values (width * height * 4)

If we take the for-loop out of your `draw()` function and execute it:

```js
let width = 10;
let height = 5;

for (var index = 0; index < width * height * 4; index += 4) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.floor(index / 4) / width);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.floor(index / 4) * width);
  console.log(`x=${x}, y=${y}`);
}
```

We can see that the max value it returns for y is 490.

If we look at the generation of the `grid` array:

```
for (var outer = 0; outer < width; outer += 1) {
  grid[outer] = [];
  for (var inner = 0; inner < height; inner += 1) {
    grid[outer][inner] = [128, 128, 128];
  }
}
```

we see that it creates a two-dimensional array, where the first dimension's max value equals the width of the canvas and the second dimension's max is of course the height of the canvas.

So if you calculate x, y that way, you simply try to set elements which are completely out the arrays bounds.

Let's correct this a little:

```js
(function() {
  var context = null;
  var grid = [];
  var height = null;
  var image_data = null;
  var width = null;

  var draw = function() {
    var data = image_data.data;
    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index += 4) {
      var x = (index / 4) % width;
      var y = Math.floor((index / 4) / width);

      data[index] = grid[x][y][0];
      data[index + 1] = grid[x][y][1];
      data[index + 2] = grid[x][y][2];
      data[index + 3] = 255;
    }
    image_data.data = data;
    context.putImageData(image_data, 0, 0);
  };

  var init = function() {
    height = jQuery(window).height();
    width = jQuery(window).width();
    jQuery('#container').html('<canvas id="map" height="' + height + '" width="' + width + '"></canvas>')
    context = document.getElementById('map').getContext('2d');
    image_data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

    for (var outer = 0; outer < width; outer += 1) {
      grid[outer] = [];
      for (var inner = 0; inner < height; inner += 1) {
        grid[outer][inner] = [128, 128, 128];
      }
    }

  }

  var start_drawing = function() {
    draw();
    // setTimeout(start_drawing, 1);
  };

  init();
  start_drawing();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```